# How to modify both the x & Y axises in my data points Jqplot chart to start from the points that are included

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqplot

i have the following data points jqplot chart in my asp.net mvc:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var line1 = [['23-May-08', 578.55], ['20-Jun-08', 566.5],
                     ['25-Jul-08', 480.88], ['22-Aug-08', 509.84],
                     ['26-Sep-08', 454.13], ['24-Oct-08', 379.75],
                     ['21-Nov-08', 303], ['26-Dec-08', 308.56],
                     ['23-Jan-09', 299.14], ['20-Feb-09', 346.51],
                     ['20-Mar-09', 325.99], ['24-Apr-09', 386.15],
                     ['26-Apr-09', 386.15], ['17-Apr-09', 386.15],
                     ['24-Apr-09', 386.15], ['24-Apr-09', 386.15]];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1],
           { title: 'Data Point Highlighting',
             axes: 
                { xaxis: 
                    { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                      tickOptions: { formatString: '%b&nbsp;%#d' }
                    },
                  yaxis: { tickOptions: { formatString: '%.2f'} }
                },
             highlighter: { show: true, sizeAdjust: 7.5 },
             cursor: { show: false }
           });
    });
</script>
```

How i can force the X-axises and Y-axises numbers to start from the first value in above Line1 values ; for example currently the x-axises will start from 17 may although the first value in the list is 23 may.

Answer (score 0):

Add inside the `xaxis` brackets this line: `pad: 0,`

```
xaxis: 
        { 
          renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          pad: 0,
          tickOptions: { formatString: '%b&nbsp;%#d' }
        },
```

It will cancel the axis start and end values padding, as the default padding is set for 1.2.

And from the [official documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.pad):

***pad***

**this.pad = 1.2**

Padding to extend the range above and below the data bounds.  The data range is multiplied by this factor to determine minimum and maximum axis bounds.  A value of 0 will be interpreted to mean no padding, and pad will be set to 1.0.

Comment: i specify the pad:0 , but it only worked on the y axises , but still the x-axises have the default padding !!!. BR

Comment: I'm not sure pad with 0 value is possible with `dateaxisranderer`. But anyway, try `pad: 1.0` to give you only 1 day tolerance.